# Как лучше организовать структуру приложения с использование WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Недавно начал разбираться с WCF, вопрос как лучше организовать структуру программы. Имеется готовый класс условно такого вида:

```
public class MyClass
{
...
public void Initialization()
public void LoadConfig(string configfile)
public void Deinitialization()
...
public int MyMethod1(int a)
public int MyMethod2(int a)
public int MyMethod3(int a)
...
}
```

Цель - организовать вызов методов класса MyClass удаленно через WCF. Также при старте WCF-службы нужно создать экземпляр этого класса, вызвать Initialization() для инициализации, загрузить конфиг. После этого перенаправить обращения к WCF-службе на вызовы методов из MyClass.
В процессе завершения работы WCF-службы (закрытия приложения) вызвать Deinitialization().

Инициальзация создает несколько потоков, которые должны постоянно работать в процессе работы WCF-службы. Всё взаимодействие с этими потоками скрыто за методами MyMethod. Deinitialization() необходима для корректного завершения работы потоков.

В каком месте лучше создавать экземпляр класса?
Где вызывать инициализацию?
Где вызывать деинициализацию?
Как вызвать методы MyClass из hosting-части программы?

За основу беру простейший пример из MSDN примерно такого вида:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRegisterService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int MyWCFMethod1(int a);

    [OperationContract]
    int MyWCFMethod2(int a);

    [OperationContract]
    int MyWCFMethod3(int a);
...
}

public class RegisterService : IRegisterService
{
    // Как вариант объявить экземпляр MyClass здесь???
    MyClass foo;

    public RegisterService()
    {
         // Создание и инициализацию разместить в конструкторе???
         foo = new MyClass();
         foo.Initialization();
         Debug.WriteLine("Initialization");
    }
    public int MyWCFMethod1(int a)
    {
       // отсюда вызываем метод MyClass.MyMethod1(...)
       foo.MyMethod1(a);
    }
    public int MyWCFMethod2(int a)
    {
       // отсюда вызываем метод MyClass.MyMethod2(...)
       foo.MyMethod2(a);
    }
    public int MyWCFMethod3(int a)
    {
       // отсюда вызываем метод MyClass.MyMethod3(...)
       foo.MyMethod3(a);
    }

    // А где разместить foo.Deinitialization() ???
    ...
}
```

Хостинг WCF-сервиса в консольном приложении

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        string configfile = args[0];
        // Как передать configfile в MyClass.LoadConfig(...)  ???
        // Как вообще вызвать оттсюда методы MyClass ???

        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RegisterService));
        // Типовые настройки
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        Uri address = new Uri("http://bla-bla-bla...");
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRegisterService), binding, address);

        // Стартуем сервис 
        serviceHost.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

В таком варианте при serviceHost.Open() не происходит вызова конструктора RegisterService(), и соответственно не вызывается MyClass.Initialization(). Вместо этого, при каждом обращении к MyWCFMethod(...) инициализация происходит заново.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит понимать, что конструктор сервиса вызывается при каждом обращении к сервису, даже из одного клиента:

```
    using (Service1Client client = new Service1Client())
    {
        client.GetData(1); // конструктов wcf-сервиса вызывается, а потом GetData
        client.GetData(2); // конструктов wcf-сервиса вызывается, а потом GetData
    }
```

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужен singleton, который будет работать в фоне, хотя могу и ошибаться, т.к. не вижу конечной цели

Поэтому:

> В каком месте лучше создавать экземпляр класса?

При первом использовании

> Где вызывать инициализацию?

При создании класса

> Где вызывать деинициализацию?

Либо при финализации объекта (см. пример ниже), либо ручками при завершении приложения-хоста вашего сервиса (это предпочтительней)

> Как вызвать методы MyClass из hosting-части программы?

MyClass же нужен клиентам, а не хостеру, немного не понимаю вопроса. в любом случае, если вопрос есть - MyClass.Instance.MyMethod1() в любом месте, где захотите

public class MyClass
{
    static object _locker = new object();
    static MyClass _instance;

```
private MyClass()
{
}

public static MyClass Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance != null)
        {
            return _instance;
        }

        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_instance != null)
            {
                return _instance;
            }

            _instance = new MyClass();

            _instance.Initialization();

            return _instance;
        }
    }
}

public void Initialization()
{

}
public void LoadConfig(string configfile)
{

}
public void Deinitialization()
{

}

public int MyMethod1(int a) { return 1; }
public int MyMethod2(int a) { return 1; }
public int MyMethod3(int a) { return 1; }

~MyClass()
{
    Deinitialization();
}
```

}

[Попробуйте эту демку, может полегче станет](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4yw5wuJ9EGXp/WcfServiceTest.rar)

Comment: пс: на коленке накидал, про singleton, c# finalize и нормальный LazyLoad сами погуглите )

Comment: Сделал по приведенному Вами примеру - задачу решил. Правда пока не до конца разобрался с использованием _instance.
По поводу конечной цели - через это условный MyClass организовано взаимодействие с аппаратной переферией. Взаимодействие не тривиальное, в фоне крутятся несколько потоков, постоянно поддерживя связь. А через WCF организуется удобный интерфейс для прикладного ПО, скрывающий сложности аппаратного взаимодейстия.

Comment: @alx75, рекомендую к прочтению https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx